# Working with associative arrays, HTML form and PHP foreach & Expression Engine

Tags: php, forms, foreach, associative-array, expressionengine

I have a HTML form which looks like this...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="comp[{url_title}][check]" value="Yes" class="checkbox" />
{if question}<input type="text" name="comp[{url_title}][answer]" value="" />{/if}

<input type="checkbox" name="comp[{url_title}][check]" value="Yes" class="checkbox" />
{if question}<input type="text" name="comp[{url_title}][answer]" value="" />{/if}

<input type="checkbox" name="comp[{url_title}][check]" value="Yes" class="checkbox" />
{if question}<input type="text" name="comp[{url_title}][answer]" value="" />{/if}
```

my vardump on $_POST looks like this...

```
array(3) {
  ["some-competition-title"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["check"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  ["third-competition"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["check"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
  }
  ["another-comp-title"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["check"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

and my foreach loop looks like this

```
foreach ($_POST['comp'] as $topkey => $input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

        echo "<div style=\"background:#fff; padding:10px;\">";
        echo "$topkey | $value ";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "</div>";

    }
}
```

which will return

```
some-competition-title | Yes 
third-competition | Yes 
third-competition | asdasd 
another-comp-title | Yes
```

OK - I'm trying to pass the foreach loop so it will combine the checkbox and the answer if the name of the array (url-title) is the same, so essentially I would like it to return this.

```
some-competition-title | Yes 
third-competition | Yes | asdasd 
another-comp-title | Yes
```

Opposed to what I have above. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to combine the subarray values into one value.

```
foreach ($_POST['comp'] as $topkey => $input) 
{
    // get the values of the subarray and assign them
    // to $value 
    $value = implode(' | ', array_values($input));

    echo "<div style=\"background:#fff; padding:10px;\">";
    echo "$topkey | $value ";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using one for loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['comp'] as $topkey => $input) {
    echo "<div style=\"background:#fff; padding:10px;\">";
    $value = '';
    if (isset($input['check']) && isset($input['answer'])) {
        $value = $topkey . " | " . $input['check'] . " | " . $input['answer'];
    } elseif (isset($input['check'])) {
        $value = $topkey . " | " . $input['check'];
    }
    echo "$topkey | $value ";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

You check whether both `check` and `answer` is present in the array, if yes the first `if` condition is true and value is taken, else if only `check` is present, the `elseif` executes.